# CMake: Absolute lib-pathnames given to target_link_library( PRIVATE ) are exported, appear in generated INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES. How do I?

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, dependency-management

In a large CMake/C++ project our major library target `Foo` is being added. It has many statically linked dependencies that are provided as absolute-paths to `target_link_libraries()`. Now I'm writing the CMake to export this library once built, including the generated CMake so a library consumer can simply use CMake `find_package()`. However the generated `FooTargets.cmake` is embeding the absolute-paths of the link-libraries instead of just the library names.

Additionally, I've already created an `add_library(BarCommon INTERFACE)`, to wrap up the referenced 3rd-party static libs separately and that seems to be working and the client-application consumed it. That accounts for 90% of the libraries also mentioned by FOO. So really FOO's exported `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` should be about 3 file names instead of 40 absolute-pathnames.

1. I'm confused, why is the `target_link_libraries(FOO PRIVATE ${libs}` is defining the exported 'INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES' property?
2. I would like that generated `INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES` property to be only library filenames, and optimally have finer control over which filenames end up in it. How do I control this?

---

**Code:**

Inside a large CMake Macro for generating targets we have this:
-

- I call it to create library/target FOO.
- `_TARGET_ARGS_LIB_DEPENDS` will resolve to *ABSOLUTE FILE PATHNAMES* for about 40 statically linked library dependencies.

```
add_library(${TargetName} STATIC ${AllSources} ${_TARGET_ARGS_OBJ_FILES})

  <snip>

target_link_libraries(${TargetName}
    PRIVATE
        $<${GCC}:-Wl,--start-group>
        ${_TARGET_ARGS_LIB_DEPENDS}
        $<${GCC}:-Wl,--end-group>
    )
```

where that longish function returns I have just added these blocks:

```
target_link_directories(FOO
    INTERFACE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:foo/lib>
    )

target_include_directories(FOO
    INTERFACE
        $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}>
        $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:foo/include>
    )

install(TARGETS Foo
    EXPORT
        FooTargets
    DESTINATION
        foo/lib
    )
```

There is some more 'install' boilerplate at the end of my CMakeLists.txt
After I run CMAKE, build the project and run the 'INSTALL' target CMake generated from Visual Studio I can examine generated file: `local_install\Release\Windows\Foo\lib\cmake\Foo\FooTargets.cmake` shows:

```
set_target_properties(Nexidia.Workbench.StaticLib.StaticLib PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/Foo/include"
  INTERFACE_LINK_DIRECTORIES "${_IMPORT_PREFIX}/Foo/lib"
  INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES "\$<LINK_ONLY:\$<0:-Wl,--start-group>>;C:/full/path/to/libA.lib;C:/full/path/to/libB.lib \$<LINK_ONLY:\$<0:-Wl,--end-group>>"
)
```

(with the full paths to about 40 libraries).

---

PS. I'm reading Professional CMake: A Practical Guide, so if someone could cite the chapter/sub-section that answers this it might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your library is *static* and so it cannot be correctly linked to consumers without including its dependencies on consumers' link lines. The same thing happens with the shared dependencies of shared libraries. Static dependencies of shared libraries are fully "absorbed" into the shared library and so they don't appear.

CMake is aware of all this, and so to respect the other semantics of `PRIVATE`, it inserts the `$<LINK_ONLY:...>` generator expression. This ensures that the libraries are used for linking *only* and that any associated `INTERFACE_*` properties are not propagated.

In other words, CMake is behaving correctly here.

You should resolve this by creating and linking to *targets* for `libB` and friends that you can either export as part of your main build or import into both your main build and via `find_dependency` in your distributed package, along with the libraries themselves, of course.

The best advice I can give you is to **always** link to **targets** in CMake, never to paths or raw library flags.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that part of the linking process and why the PRIVATE label doesn't hide these sub-dependencies. 

While 3rd party static dependencies (LibA, libB, etc) are linked to target Foo using absolute pathnames for a reason, these paths will obviously not be valid when the exported library is moved to a different machine. Is there a way to get CMake to reduce those paths to filenames in the generated FooTargets.cmake?

Comment: Those library files are being exported and made available to the consumer for linking. As I mentioned I created a INTERFACE target BAR to roll-up all the 3rd-party static libraries, for our consumers benefit. We're shifting to targets as dependencies are updated, but this is enterprise software and eliminating the pathname references will be a huge undertaking, not a quick fix.

Comment: @Garrick - If you link to an absolute path, you will export an absolute path. You can instead link to an IMPORTED target, which will export as a target name. You would define this target differently inside your build (via absolute pathnames, say) than after export (via arbitrary logic in your ProjectConfig.cmake file). This is a local change and not a massive undertaking.